# multiple websocket connections for load testing

Tags: node.js, websocket, load-testing

I want to run a load test for a server recently developed in node.js .The problem is i am not sure if and how is it possible to establish multiple connections from one client to this one port of the server.Particularly,should there be different event listeners for every websocket that is going to be created,for example w[i].on('open',function(){....}  or am i under the wrong impression?

Answer (score 0):

If the websocket server was developed in nodejs, you can easily use [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest) tool.

> Runs a load test on the selected HTTP or WebSockets URL. The API allows for easy integration in your own tests.

This lets you to test web sockets and http URLs. It is available as a package on NPM.